# Не работает событие onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

сразу же извиняюсь, если ошибка была глупой. 
Есть изображение, при нажатии на него, див с ид фильтр должен становиться блочным.
Проблема: при нажатии ничего не происходит.

HTML:

```
 <img  src="img/himiya/galery/g_him_1.jpg"  class="g_image"  id='img_1_1' onclick="shows('block')">
```

CSS:

```
#filter{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 30;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
}
.g_image{
width: 24%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function shows(state) {
      $('#filter').css({'display':state});
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функции `show` нет в глобальной области видимости, она - локальная внутри обработчика `ready`.

```
<img  src="img/himiya/galery/g_him_1.jpg"  class="g_image"  id='img_1_1'>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function shows(state) {
    $('#filter').css({'display':state});
  }
  $("#img_1_1").click(function() { shows('block'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
const img = document.getElementById('img_1_1');

img.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $('#filter').css({'display':state});
});
```